# the method does not check the value properly

Tags: java, sql, methods, oracle11g

```
static boolean checkCode(String Code, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement s; 
        String cc = null;
        try {
            String Statement = "SELECT Code from Courses where Code="+ Code;
            s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(Statement);
            while (rs.next()) {
                cc = rs.getString("Code");   
            }

            if((Code.equalsIgnoreCase(cc)))
                return true;

            else
               return false;

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {} 
        return false;
    }
```

I am using switch case and 3 cases aren't working properly ( delete using the course's code, update using the course's code, and view specific course using the course's code ) so I think the error in checkCode method. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting a value where a value is equal to itself. I would just get a count of matching records. Next, you aren't closing any of the resources you open in your method. And, you are silently swallowing any exceptions that occur. Finally, you aren't using `PreparedStatement` so your query (at least at first glance) is vulnerable to sql injection.

Something like,

```
static boolean checkCode(String Code, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT count(*) from Courses where Code=?";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        ps.setString(1, Code);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getInt(1) > 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```